# Unable to install pip for base

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

please i am new to python. I was able to have pip install for other packages working fine.
But i am unable to install pip for base (pip install base), i got the error below;

```
Collecting base   Using cached base-1.0.4.tar.gz (3.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, toke nize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_d1d716d3f34241b9bbcd57356a164 223\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_d1d716d3f34241b9bbcd 57356a164223\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.St ringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close(); exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-fn 47qk0n'
         cwd: C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_d1d716d3f34241b9bbcd57356a164223\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_d1d716d3f34241b9bbcd57356a164223\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_d1d716d3f34241b9bbcd57356a164223\setup.py", line 21, in read
        return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
    ---------------------------------------- WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/e5/464fcdb2cdbafc65f0b2da261dda861fa51d80e1a4985a2bb00ced 080549/base-1.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=b2fbb9f44c272335a80510221cfc0d8b137f11052e70ce8ff154b8213b16fb66 (from https://pypi.org/ simple/base/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.   Using cached base-1.0.1.tar.gz (2.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, toke nize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_1e98d46b217c49e2a8b5e297a43b8 2c9\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_1e98d46b217c49e2a8b5 e297a43b82c9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.St ringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close(); exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-yx xpmgo6'
         cwd: C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_1e98d46b217c49e2a8b5e297a43b82c9\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_1e98d46b217c49e2a8b5e297a43b82c9\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_1e98d46b217c49e2a8b5e297a43b82c9\setup.py", line 21, in read
        return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
    ---------------------------------------- WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/d0/cefa4511620a90c1d6f4b1dc879c3d7031a4ad4b449513b73f0830 35baab/base-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=49e5e80e6a8d0c85d712ba3b4dcf3f30d948cd10331fa77ef1a335c172c95657 (from https://pypi.org/ simple/base/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.   Using cached base-1.0.0.tar.gz (2.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, toke nize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_804fcc06c3a44ef7901b8b9c2ec64 8d5\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\tayo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xoxzupue\\base_804fcc06c3a44ef7901b 8b9c2ec648d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.St ringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close(); exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-p3 hceh7v'
         cwd: C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_804fcc06c3a44ef7901b8b9c2ec648d5\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_804fcc06c3a44ef7901b8b9c2ec648d5\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
      File "C:\Users\tayo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xoxzupue\base_804fcc06c3a44ef7901b8b9c2ec648d5\setup.py", line 21, in read
        return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "c:\users\tayo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
    ---------------------------------------- WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/df/54eb395ead68553286c466d5ba2abf4e5ad9286772178ca4a649b9 168956/base-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d4048887db94c5e919589c78294c87ff8d7ac16e2f899f53b45b4891a8ae878e (from https://pypi.org/ simple/base/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement base (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.4) ERROR: No matching distribution found for base
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried `pip install base` as well, and I get the same error. I'm guessing it's a problem with the package itself.

Answer (score -1):

So i what i was doing wrong was not importing the Base variable from the database.py file. I thought the Base was an external library. So i changed my import to
"from database import Base" where the database is the database.py in the same package directory